# 406 when using Guzzle but not through browser, or command line cURL or wget

Tags: php, curl, rss, guzzle

we have a php web app using Guzzle 5 to download Wordpress RSS feeds.

It's working fine except for this feed https://www.socialquant.net/blog/feed/

The owner of this site *does* want us to pull the feed, and is not knowingly attempting to block access.

I can successfully download the file from my local machine and from the production web server (where we initially noticed the problem) using `wget` or `curl` with no special options.

This happened once before and that time we believed the issue to be caused by mod_security on Apache and it was solved by adding an arbitrary User-Agent header. But that time I was able to reproduce the issue consistently on the command line, this time it's only failing through Guzzle/PHP

I've copied the response headers from a browser request to the problem feed, and another feed that is working. I crossed off those that were the same and was left with the below

```
Server:Apache/2.2.22
Vary:User-Agent
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.29
Content-Encoding:gzip

Server:Apache
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.30
```

That's not offering much insight. The gzip content encoding jumps out, I'm trying to find another working feed using gzip to verify this but it shouldn't matter as Guzzle's default mode is to automatically handle encoding. And we're using the same settings to download images from CDNs which are using gzip.

Does anyone have any ideas please? Thanks :)

*EDIT*

Using Guzzle 5.3.0

Code:

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

```
try {
    $res = $client->get( $feed, [
      'headers' => ['User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/4.0']
    ] );
} catch (\Exception $e) {

}
```

Comment: Could you show the Guzzle part of the code and precise version of Guzzle 5 you are using?

Comment: Just edited the post, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't have a *proper* solution to your problem, but I have it working again.

**tl;dr version**

It's the User-Agent header, changing it to pretty much anything else works.

This `wget` call fails:

```
wget -d --header="User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0"  https://www.socialquant.net/blog/feed/
```

but this works

```
wget -d --header="User-Agent: SomeRandomText" https://www.socialquant.net/blog/feed/
```

And with that, the PHP below now also works:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$feed = 'https://www.socialquant.net/blog/feed/';

try {

    $res = $client->get( 
        $feed, 
        [
            'headers' => [
                'User-Agent' => 'SomeRandomText',
            ]
        ]
    );
    echo $res->getBody();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

**My thoughts**

I started with `wget` and `curl` as you pointed out, which works when no special headers or options are set. Opening it in my browser also worked. I also tried using Guzzle without the `User-Agent` set and that also works.

Once I set the `User-Agent` to `Mozilla/4.0` or even `Mozilla/5.0` it started failing with `406 Not Acceptable`

According to the [HTTP Status Code definitions](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), a 406 means

> The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the request.

In theory, adding `Accept` and `Accept-Encoding` headers should resolve the issue, but it didn't. Not via Guzzle or `wget`.

I then found the [Mozilla Developer Network definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/Response_codes) which states:

> This response is sent when the web server, after performing server-driven content negotiation, doesn't find any content following the criteria given by the **user agent**.

This kinda points at the `User-Agent` again. This led me to believe that you are indeed correct that mod_security is doing something odd. I am convinced that an update to mod_security or Apache on the client's servers added a rule to parse the `Mozilla/*` user agents in a specific way since sending the `User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 ()` also works.

That's why I'm saying I don't have a proper solution for you. Even though the client *wants* you to pull the feed, they (or their hosting) is still in control of the rules.

**Note:** I noticed my IP getting blacklisted after a number of failed 406 attempts, after which I had to wait an hour before I could access the site again. Most likely a mod_security rule. mod_security *might* even be picking up on the automated requests with your user agent and start blocking it or rejecting it with the 406.

Comment: This is an absolutely fantastic reply Donovan! We added the Mozilla/4.0 User-Agent header arbitrarily a few weeks ago due to a blank user agent causing a 406 from a different Apache server.

Comment: Seeing your command line debug steps, made me realise I was accidentally passing 'Mozilla/4.0' into the Accepts header while testing using cURL. Very annoyed at myself for that one

Comment: Although you say you haven't found a proper solution, you have. It is that we need to use a User-Agent header that works in all cases. Thank you very much

Comment: No problem! I think I was set on finding the right combination of headers to allow `User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0` to work since I can't see any reason for it not to. Good luck on finding the User-Agent that works in all cases!

Comment: Added a portion of my genuine user agent and both problem feeds are allowing the request 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution for you either, as I'm also experiencing this same issue (except I get error 503 and it fails 60% of the time). Let me know if you have found a solution.

However, I would like to share with you what I have found through my recent research. I found that certain User-Agents work better than others for me. This makes me believe that it's not what Donovan states to be the case (at least for me).

When I set User-Agent to null, it works 100% of the time. However, I haven't made any large requests yet, as I'm afraid of getting IP banned, as I know I would with a large request.

When I do a var_dump of the request itself, I see a lot of arrays which include Guzzle markers. I'm thinking, maybe Amazons detection services can tell that I'm spoofing the headers? I don't know.

Hope you figured it out.